# Manga about a class kidnapped and forced to play a game made by wealthy people or they would blow them with bomb-like collars

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character (MC) is isekaied and retuns to reality with his powers. His classmates and himself are kidnapped and forced to play a game made by wealthy people or they would blow them with bomb-like collars. The MC's friends hacked the cameras and made the game live. The MC overturned the game by teleporting the collars on the wealthy people and forced them to denounce their own crimes.

Comment: So what does the isekai have to do with the storyline then?  The storyline described doesn't seem on-topic on its own.

Comment: Does he come back with powers? A System? ALlies from the other realm? A new perspective on life?

Comment: Yes he retains his powers

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-isekai-returnee-is-too-op-for-the-modern-world/recommendations might have some pointers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_the_Gods_Will ?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Isekaigaeri no Moto Yuusha Desu ga, Death Game ni Makikomaremashita](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekaigaeri-no-moto-yuusha-desu-ga-death-game-ni-makikomaremashita)*.

> He was living a peaceful life as any normal high schooler would, until one day he and his classmates were suddenly brought to uninhabited island. "I'll have you guys kill each other until there's only one of you remaining." Hearing these words from the man strangely dressed in a military uniform, his classmates panicked. ... However, they were unaware that **the hero who was hailed as the strongest had just recently returned from another world**. The organizers behind the game were already out of luck by the time the game started as the expectations they had for death game that they had worked so desperately to set up would be unwittingly crushed before them.

The story opens with high school kids going on a bus to a field trip, with the protagonist, Ise Kaito, being more enthusiastic than the others. Fog appears around them while they're in transit and goes into the bus, knocking everyone asleep. They wake up in a classroom with a man in military uniform stating that they must fight in a death game or will be executed by him.

The protagonist reveals to the reader that he just returned from another world, but still has all his powers, and uses them to completely shut down the death game. This includes "teleporting" the collars into his item box,

[image]

teleporting to the organizers of the death game after a classmate hacks their computers, duplicating the explosive collars and attaching them to everyone's necks, and forces them to denounce each other in order to have the collars removed.

[image]